# Determining Minimum Integer Weights for a Probability Distribution

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I am looking for a way to get minimal integer weights to arrive at a given probability distribution.

For instance if I was given the set of probabilities
$\{0.326923076923077, 0.615384615384615, 0.0576923076923077\}$ that would correspond to integer weights of $\{17, 32, 3\}$ or $\{34,64,6\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need the exact values of your probabilities so that the following method works.

So you have  $p_i$ and you want to find $n_i$ so that   $\frac{n(i)}{\Sigma_{j=1}^{n} n_j}=p_i$

All the ratios $p_i/p_j$ are rational, so you can :

Take all $p_0/p_j$, compute their minimum fraction (by finding the best rational approximation a finite number of time or by observing the infinite decimal writing). Call this fraction $k_j/m_j$.

$n_0$ will be the LCM of all the $k_j$ . You can then compute each $n_j$ as $m_j  n_0/k_j$